# Angular hijri date and time picker

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, hijri

Currently we need a Angular hijri date and time picker in one of our projects.
Online we could find only angular date picker in hijri. Any reference would be helpful.
The calendar should use 1441 as current year instead of 2019.

Comment: you can use  ng-bootstrap  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/calendars#islamicumalqura

Comment: OR https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Hijri date with the angular material date picker. It was surprisingly supported by them since they support localization you can find that on their documentation [datepicker-locale](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-locale)

The only issue I have faced is that I have to discover the right local to generate Hijri dates `'ar-sa'`

```js
this._adapter.setLocale('ar-sa');
```